# Error in getting data from excel: Invalid header signature

Tags: java, excel, file, exception, file-upload

I am trying to read a `.xlsx` Excel file but I am getting an exception:

> Error in getting data from excel Invalid header signature; read
>   1688935826934608, expected -2226271756974174256

What is the thing that I am missing?

My code is

```
            FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath + "\\"
                    + "uploadAreaExcel.xlsx");
            HSSFWorkbook workbook;

            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
            HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");

            System.out.println("Total Count :"
                    + Integer.toString(worksheet.getLastRowNum()));
            for(int i=1;i<worksheet.getLastRowNum();i++){
                HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(i);
                HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.getCell((short) 0);
                System.out.println(cellA1.getStringCellValue());
                HSSFCell cellB1 = row1.getCell((short) 1);
                System.out.println(cellB1.getStringCellValue());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in getting data from excel "+e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide us with code sample and data sample?

Comment: Please check the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I see that you are using HSSF to handle .xlsx file. But HSSF doesn't support .xlsx, you should give a try to [XSSF workbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html).